# Scala and Writing map functions

Tags: scala, functional-programming

So suppose I have a function that expects a Set with definition `Int => Boolean` and a function `f` like this:

`def map(s: Set, f: Int => Int): Set = {}`

Now how do I apply this `f` to each element of this set `s`.

```
def map(s: Set, f: Int => Int): Set = { (i: Int) => f(s(i)) }
```

Which is ofcourse incorrect because in `f(s(i))`, 's(i)' returns a boolean, and thus can't apply `f` on it. Problem is how do I access each element of Set and apply this `f` on it?

This question is part of Coursera's Functional Programming with Scala course.

Comment: If this is about the coursera course, you should tag this as homework. Also, you can't do it without iterating through all possible values that might be in the set, for the coursera exercise.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral no, [he should not tag it as homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: He should acknowledge it's homework in the question itself, then

Comment: @Daniel, there was no Homework tag. Thus I did not.

Comment: @Paul yes, let me do it in the post instead.

Answer (score 5):

A goal of the course is to help you understand the functional model, and in this case, how the Set can be represented by a function (called the charasteristic function for that set).

Instead of the final solution, here's a hint on how to reason about this problem:

Given the characteristic function  `f: Int => Boolean` that defines your set and `x`, an Int, if `f(x) == true`, then x belongs to the Set. Now, if you have a function `g:Int=>Int`
 that you want to map over the set, what you want is to apply that function to the elements that you know that belong to the set: `if (f(x)) then g(x)`.

Try to apply that thinking to your exercise.

Comment: Thanks a ton, @maasg for the clear reply. Though I will be absolutely grateful if you can clear this to me: 'if (f(x)) then g(x)' is in anyway equivalent to 'y =>  x == f(y)', a trickery of Scala syntax that I am unaware of?

Comment: No those are different expressions. `y => x == f(y)` is a lambda expression saying "given `y`, for an `x` (from the closure context) it returns true if `x` is equal to `f(y)`

Comment: @user1343318 what you are looking for is the set of elements such that  for each element `y` of the resulting set, there should be an element `x` in the original set that complies to the condition that `f(x)==y` that's where your expression `y => x == f(y)` is aiming at, but it's still missing something...

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote the exists function correctly:

```
def map(s: Set, f: Int => Int): Set = (i: Int) => exists(s, (x: Int) => i == f(x))
```

Bam one line!

Answer (score -3):

You need to use fold to do this.

```
def map(s: Set[Int], f: Int => Int): Set[Int] = 
    s.foldLeft(Set.empty[Int])((s,i) => s+f(i))
```

Comment: Well, f still isnt applied yet. Shouldnt it be      s.foldLeft(Set.empty[Int])((s,i) => s+f(i)) ?

Comment: The question deals with a specific definition of Set: `Set with definition Int => Boolean` to which your proposed solution will not apply